# How to use context.io in .net selenium project?

Tags: c#, selenium, contextio, mailinator

I am using selenium webdriver in C#, and i want to test an application's registration page.
I am facing some issues:

1. The application does-not allow user deletion.
2. I **cannot create new user account randomly** as i have to validate the user
   account with the user's email account. **So, each time i have to
   create new mail account**, which is not possible.
3. I have thought of using **mailinator** but it is not secured.

So, i googled a lot and it seemed context.io could be a good option. But, i can't understand how do i **implement context.io in .net project**. There is no information about .net packages in the documentation they have provided. If i can't implement context.io in .net project then I need to know, **is there any other way to solve this problem?**

Comment: I don't think this is specflow related, so you should remove that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got my solution to my problem. I have implemented context.io. There we have to create an account and for testing we should use  + @gmail.com.